# Inspect Deleted Item in Acrobat

Tags: adobe, acrobat, arcobjects

I'm using Acrobat Pro 9.5 to examine a PDF and found it has two elements, a cropped item and a deleted one.  Is it possible to inspect these items?  I'd like to see the deleted object and what was cropped.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "examine"? Are you using the Preflight tool?

Comment: I have not tried the Preflight tool.  I open the document and select Document | Examine Document from the menu bar.  A pop up is shown and a the document is analyzed, after which the dialog shows a tree with the object listed.  I can remove the items but not inspect the original or get details of what they are.  I've added an image to the question to explain it better.

Comment: You won't be able to get any more details from that tool but there are other tools that will let you walk the PDF object tree and get highly detailed information. I can't make any specific recommendations though.